# How to extract information from single line text with no html class?

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape my first website (https://news.ycombinator.com/jobs) using scrapy and python.The information that i need to extract is as follows:
- The name of the company that is hiring
- The location of the company 
- The position that the ad is for

There are no separate tags for these fields in page html.And text has no specific pattern. 
 e.g.
ZeroCater (YC W11) Is Hiring a Principal Engineer in SF: Must Love Food

Regex alone is not sufficient to extract this information. Is there any efficient and easy solution to this problem?

I have tried python regex. I also studied about NLP and and text classification using nltk. But nltk will increase complexity of code and it is time consuming.

Comment: Didn't understand, why regex not alone sufficient to extract. Isn't the `ZeroCater` is company and `SF` is the location in your given example?

Comment: Just for the record, HackerNews has an API and you don't have to scrape the website: https://github.com/HackerNews/API

Comment: This question is too broad and has nothing to do with web-scraping or scrapy. You want to extract structured data from unstructured text. There's no way to do it that would fit in a single answer. You need a smart natural language processing system that is trained to understand job titles and locations. You should look into `nltk` package. Alternatively you can just cover some patterns and extract _some_ data but you won't achieve high coverage when your parsed text has no strict structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i will do in this case is trying to find any pattern to help me extract these data, 
for example i can see these words are frequent `"is hiring|is looking for|is looking to hire|hiring"` and company name comes first, also location come after `in`:

this is just a small trial and you can extend it to get what you need

```
import re
text = """ZeroCater (YC W11) Is Hiring a Principal Engineer in SF: Must Love Food (zerocater.com)
OneSignal Is Hiring Full Stack Engineers in San Mateo (onesignal.com)
Faire (YC W17) Is Looking to Hire Business Operations Leads (greenhouse.io)
InsideSherpa (YC W19) Is Hiring Software Engineers in Sydney (workable.com)
Jerry (YC S17) Is Hiring Senior Software Dev, Data Engineer (Toronto/Remote) (getjerry.com)
Iris Automation Is Hiring an Account Executive for B2B Flying Vehicle Software (irisonboard.com)"""

data = text.lower().splitlines()

for i, line in enumerate(data):
    # getting company name
    data[i] = re.split(r'is hiring|is looking for|is looking to hire|hiring', line)

    # job title and location if present
    data[i][1] = re.split(r' in ', data[i][1])

print('company --- Job Title --- Location')
for c in data:
    print(f'{c[0]} --- {c[1][0]} --- {c[1][1] if len(c[1])>1 else ""}')
```

output:

```
company --- Job Title --- Location
zerocater (yc w11)  ---  a principal engineer --- sf: must love food (zerocater.com)
onesignal  ---  full stack engineers --- san mateo (onesignal.com)
faire (yc w17)  ---  business operations leads (greenhouse.io) --- 
insidesherpa (yc w19)  ---  software engineers --- sydney (workable.com)
jerry (yc s17)  ---  senior software dev, data engineer (toronto/remote) (getjerry.com) --- 
iris automation  ---  an account executive for b2b flying vehicle software (irisonboard.com) ---
```

sure this code needs a lot of modifications to get a reliable results but at least its a start

Comment: Thanks everyone for help. I tried spacy and ne-chunk for named entity recognition but i could not get correct results from any of these. Finally i tried a mixture of nltk and regex. I used nltk for pos tagging only and used regex for pattern matching. The results are much better now. Still need some improvements. I think the best solution is to train my own classifier using machine learning. But obviously that will require time and hard work.